# Odd Phenomenon with removeRoot()

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I was working on implementing my own `TreeSet` when I came across an unexplainable phenomenon. One of the methods necessary to write was `public boolean remove(Comparable value` which uses `private TreeNode remove(TreeNode root, Comparable value)` and `private TreeNode removeRoot(TreeNode root)`. The methods are included below.

My problem is a discrepancy between two the results of two separate `removeRoot(TreeNode root)` methods, when they should be doing the exact same thing. The implementation is different, but why are the results?

To clarify, each `TreeNode` has a right and left child, as it's a binary tree. The `TreeNode` class contains the methods:

```
public Comparable getValue() { return value; } 
public TreeNode getLeft() { return left; } 
public TreeNode getRight() { return right; }

public void setValue(Comparable theNewValue) { value = theNewValue; }
public void setLeft(TreeNode theNewLeft) { left = theNewLeft; }
public void setRight(TreeNode theNewRight) { right = theNewRight; }
```

Below is the Tester class, `public remove()`, `private remove()`,`removeRoot()`, and both results. Assume everything has been added correctly to the tree.

**remove methods**

```
public boolean remove(Comparable value){
    if(!this.contains(value)){return false;}
    else{
        this.remove(rootVal, value);
        representation=this.toString();
        return true;
    }
}

private TreeNode remove(TreeNode root, Comparable value){
    if(root!=null){
        if(rootVal.getValue().compareTo(value)==0){
            rootVal=this.removeRoot(root);
            count--;
            return rootVal;
        }
        if(root.getLeft()!=null && root.getLeft().getValue().compareTo(value)==0){
            root.setLeft(this.removeRoot(root.getLeft()));
            count--;
            return root;
        }
        else if(root.getRight()!=null && root.getRight().getValue().compareTo(value)==0){
            root.setRight(this.removeRoot(root.getRight()));
            count--;
            return root;
        }
        if(root.getLeft()!=null && root.getValue().compareTo(value)>0){remove(root.getLeft(), value);}
        if(root.getRight()!=null && root.getValue().compareTo(value)<0){remove(root.getRight(), value);}
    }
    return rootVal;
}
```

**removeRoot() #1**

```
private TreeNode removeRoot(TreeNode root){
    TreeNode original=root;
    if(root.getLeft()==null){return root.getRight();}
    else if(root.getRight()==null){return root.getLeft();}

    root=root.getRight();
    if(root.getLeft()==null){
        root.setLeft(original.getLeft());
        return root;
    }
    TreeNode previous=null;
    while(root.getLeft()!=null){
        root=root.getLeft();
        if(root.getLeft()!=null && root.getLeft().getLeft()!=null){previous=root;}
    }
    if(previous!=null){previous.setLeft(root.getRight());}
    root.setLeft(original.getLeft());
    root.setRight(original.getRight());
    return root;
}
```

**Output #1**

```
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 3:
true
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
false
Remove 16:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 17:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 5:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 6:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 7:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
```

**removeRoot() #2**

```
private TreeNode removeRoot(TreeNode root)
{
    TreeNode temp = root.getRight();
    TreeNode prev = temp;
    if(temp == null) {
        return root.getLeft();
    }
    if(temp.getLeft() == null)
    {
        temp.setLeft(root.getLeft());
        return temp;
    }
    while(temp.getLeft() != null) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp.getLeft();
    }
    temp.setLeft(root.getLeft());
    prev.setLeft(temp.getRight());
    temp.setRight(root.getRight());
    return temp;
}
```

**Output #2**

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 3:
true
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
false
Remove 16:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 17:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 5:
 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
Remove 6: //java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
```

**Tester Method**

```
TreeSet ts1 = new TreeSet();
    ts1.add(new Integer(5));
    ts1.add(new Integer(3));
    ts1.add(new Integer(4));
    ts1.add(new Integer(15));
    ts1.add(new Integer(10));
    ts1.add(new Integer(20));
    ts1.add(new Integer(7));
    ts1.add(new Integer(13));
    ts1.add(new Integer(6));
    ts1.add(new Integer(8));
    ts1.add(new Integer(9));
    ts1.add(new Integer(11));
    ts1.add(new Integer(12));
    ts1.add(new Integer(14));
    ts1.add(new Integer(17));
    ts1.add(new Integer(16));
    ts1.add(new Integer(18));
    ts1.add(new Integer(19));
    ts1.add(new Integer(23));
    ts1.add(new Integer(21));
    ts1.add(new Integer(22));
    ts1.add(new Integer(25));
    ts1.add(new Integer(24));

    ts1.add(new Integer(1));
    ts1.add(new Integer(0));
    ts1.add(new Integer(2));
    ts1.add(new Integer(5));   //notice that 5 is added twice
    ts1.add(new Integer(17));  //notice that 17 is added twice
    ts1.add(new Integer(4));   //notice that 4 is added twice

    System.out.println(ts1);
    System.out.println("Remove 3:");
    System.out.println(ts1.remove(new Integer(3)));
    System.out.println(ts1);
    System.out.println(ts1.remove(new Integer(3)));
    System.out.println("Remove 16:");
    ts1.remove(new Integer(16));
    System.out.println(ts1);
    System.out.println("Remove 17:");
    ts1.remove(new Integer(17));
    System.out.println(ts1);
    System.out.println("Remove 5:");
    ts1.remove(new Integer(5));
    System.out.println(ts1);
    System.out.println("Remove 6:");
    ts1.remove(new Integer(6));
    System.out.println(ts1);
    System.out.println("Remove 7:");
    ts1.remove(new Integer(7));
    System.out.println(ts1);
```

Comment: With method 2, when you remove 5, it removes 5 AND 7?

Comment: @mttdbrd yes and 7, 8, and 9, which are all in the same branch of the tree if you draw it out. They are in the same branch as previous, but I can't tell why that's happening.

Comment: Your TreeSet implements SortedSet and NavigableSet, right?

Comment: @mttdbrd no implementation of any interface, but assume all the methods mentioned work as you'd expect them to.